# Jquery Crossfade on click

Tags: jquery

I have following java script that fading images in and out. In html itall positioned absolute with z-index specified from 1 to 12. 2 arrows:left and right.

It's all auto-play, I need to have each of those functions to do same fading but clicking left and right arrows: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rJ4ZA/)

```
     var fadeInTime = 1000; fadeOutTime = 1000;


     function Slide11() {
          $("#slide11").fadeIn(fadeInTime, 'linear', function () {
            Slide12();
        });
     }

    function Slide10() {
        $("#slide10").delay(500).fadeIn(fadeInTime, 'linear', function () {
        Slide11();
       });
    }

    function Slide9() {
    $("#slide9").fadeIn(fadeInTime, 'linear').delay(2000).fadeOut(fadeOutTime,'linear', function () {                
       Slide10();
        });
   }

 function Slide8() {
    $("#slide8").delay(500).fadeIn(fadeInTime, 'linear', function () {
      Slide9();
   });
}

    function Slide7() {
      $("#slide7").fadeIn(fadeInTime, 'linear').delay(2000).fadeOut(fadeOutTime,'linear', function () {
       Slide8();
       });
   }

    function Slide6() {
       $("#slide6").delay(500).fadeIn(fadeInTime, 'linear', function () {
          Slide7();
        });
   }

function Slide5() {
    $("#slide5").fadeIn(fadeInTime, 'linear').delay(2000).fadeOut(fadeOutTime,'linear', function () {
        Slide6();
    });
}


   function Slide4() {
       $("#slide4").delay(500).fadeIn(fadeInTime, 'linear', function () {
        Slide5();
      });
   }
    function Slide3() {
      $("#slide3").fadeIn(fadeInTime, 'linear').delay(2000).fadeOut(fadeOutTime,'linear', function () {
        Slide4();
       });
    }



   function Slide2() {

    $("#slide1").delay(2000).fadeOut(fadeInTime, 'linear', function () {
       $("#slide2").fadeIn(fadeInTime, 'linear', function () {
        Slide3();
       });
    });
 }


  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#slide1").hide();
    $("#slide2").hide();
    $("#slide3").hide();
    $("#slide4").hide();
    $("#slide5").hide();
    $("#slide6").hide();
    $("#slide7").hide();
    $("#slide8").hide();
    $("#slide9").hide();
    $("#slide10").hide();
    $("#slide11").hide();
    $("#slide12").hide();
    $("#colorstory").css("display", "");

    $("#slide1").fadeIn(200, 'linear', function () {
        Slide2();
        });

});
```

Comment: Where should we click here?

Comment: You know you can target multiple elements in a jQuery selector right? `$('#slide1, #slide2, #slide3').hide();` etc... or even use a class on them all and one call to hide them.. Also what if you wanted to add more slides? Also have to add new functions and other lines of code? You're already seeing inconsistency, with your delays all being different because some are using the global var and others aren't